# Using a capacitor to smooth momentary voltage cuts

Tags: capacitor, servo, smoothing-capacitor

I'm building a model of a trolleytruck (very similar to a trolleybus). The steering system works with a servo but, because the overhead wires are not perfect and there are short voltage cuts, the servo moves randomly. I'm thinking of connecting a capacitor to smooth the voltage but I can't find any information on Google (everything that I can find is about rectifier circuits). So my questions are: Can I directly connect a capacitor between the servo power wires to smooth the voltage? If that's possible, how can I calculate the capacitance that it should have?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Yes you can. Calculating the precise capacitance is always a bit tricky as you must know the exact current (or energy if you will) the servo will pull from the rail. You might want to Google for 'Bulk capacitor' as a start. Get yourself a electrolytic capacitor with the appropriate voltage and a capacitance of anywhere between 100u and 500u, place it between V+ and GND close to the servo. Be advised, these kind of caps are polarized, so place it correctly.

Comment: Yes you can. Depending on the current and break time the capacitor MAY need to be large. Voltage drop is ~= V= T.I/C (Volts seconds Amps capacitance).You can rearrange that as C = t.i/V or other.

Comment: You might need a big capacitor. That then might upset your power supply as a big capacitor gives a large inrush current. You can then also get large sparks when your trolley truck re-connects to the wire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.
Depending on the current and break time the capacitor MAY need to be large.
Voltage drop is ~=
V= T x I / C (Volts seconds Amps capacitance).You can rearrange that as
C = T x I /V or other.

eg for a 0.1V drop for a 50 ms break at 100 mA  .
C = T x I / V
= 0.05 x 0.1 / 0.1 = 0.05 Farad = 50,000 uF  (!)
Change the values to suit.